# on("mouseover') и on("mouseout') jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, функции

Как сделать так, чтоб при наведении на некоторый текст, он изменялся, а при уходе курсора с него он становился таким, каким был до наведения курсора. Нужно чтобы он именно возвращал прежний текст с оформлением, а не записывал такой же на его место.

Comment: `css: hover` можно использовать. зачем jquery в данном случае - непонятно. В любом случае в заголовке указаны некоторые события, почему бы не попробовать их использовать?

Comment: да, надо менять видимость 2х взаимоисключающих текстов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например так:

```css
.default { color: #045acf; font-weight: bold; }
.hidden { color: #800; font-weight: bold; display: none;}

.moo:hover .default {display: none;}
.moo:hover .hidden {display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<p class="moo">
  С точки зрения банальной эрудиции, <span class="default">каждый индивидуум</span><span class="hidden">не каждый сапиенс</span>, критически мотивирующий абстракцию, <span class="default">не</span> может игнорировать поляризаторы утопического субъективизма.
</p>
```

Это могут быть и целые блоки текста:

```css
.hidden {display: none;}

.mama:hover .default {display: none;}

.mama:hover .hidden {display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<div class="mama">
  <p class="default">С точки зрения банальной эрудиции, каждый индивидуум, критически мотивирующий абстракцию, не может игнорировать поляризаторы утопического субъективизма.</p>
  <p class="hidden">Lorem ipsum dolor amet...</p>
</div>
```